# MySQL not working through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm creating a login page, and I have this code to check if a user with a given username exists. Here's the code:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = $tuser');
return mysql_result($query, 0)==1;
```

I know that the value of $tuser exists in the database, and when I run the same code in SQL with the value instead of $tuser it works fine, and returns 1 as it should. But this code returns 0, any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you've not quoted `$tuser`

Comment: `$query = mysql_query(....) or die(mysql_error());` will tell you exactly what's wrong...

Comment: Use this: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = '$tuser'");` and check if connected `$query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = '$tuser'");` --- `$con` being your DB connection.

Comment: Somebody paste your "use mysqli or PDO" boilerplate here.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Thanks @JasonMcCreary... also, nice blog.

Comment: @fred: -1. You've inverted the arguments. mysql doesn't require a connection argument, and it'd be the LAST argument anyways.

Comment: I tried adding the quotes, but it still didn't work.

Comment: That's what I posted originally, and thought I had made a mistake. Anyway, the OP should be using `mysqli_*` so I was partially right. @MarcB

Comment: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = '$tuser'",$con);` <= I stand corrected.

Comment: Thanks Marc B, I used mysql_error() and realized that the problem was in the previous code!

Comment: Thanks @Digital Chris. The OP should also read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a simple syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = '. $tuser);
```

or

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = $tuser");
```

Single-quote strings `'` are plain text with no support special case.
Double-quoted strings `"` have interpolation so you can insert to string  a variable with its value e.g `echo "My name is $name"` or you can formatting string by special printer chars e.g `\n`, `\r`.
More about [String Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation)

Comment: Good edit. @Digital Chris - don't troll :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try: `"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = '$tuser'"`

Comment: Yes, I know. But seems that if you do not dissuade users about using old mysql functions in every single answer you are automatically downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is placed in the incorrect type of quotes for string substitution. You have it as follows with single quotes (ie: `'`):

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = $tuser');
```

But you might mean this. Please note the double quotes (ie: `"`):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = $tuser");
```

Another way is this:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = ' . $tuser);
```

And I prefer `sprintf()` and separating the query from the actual database call like this:

```
$real_query = sprintf('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = %s', $tuser);
$query = mysql_query($real_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = '{$tuser}'");
```

But access by MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. It is **better use PDO and parameters in SQL sequence to prevent SQL injection**.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = '{$tuser}'
```

is vulnerable for SQL injection. Try

```
user: 1' OR '' ='
```